# Vulkan validation layer CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT Allocator is NULL

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am trying to follow https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ and a Udemy course on my journey to understand Vulkan.
So far I was able to follow everything but the validation layers are not working and I have no idea why.
Tried the following:

- check for typos
- check validation layer present in vulkan configurator
- installed sdk on 2 separate devices
- pushed code around and asked the instructor on Udemy.

So far I have found the following:

- Instance creation is successful
- Instance is passed into

  static VkResult CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pDebugMessenger)

The problem I have managed to isolate by breakpoints is that pAllocator is NULL.

Github Repo can be found here: https://github.com/b34s7m0d3/VulkanImplementation

I'm trying to be proper and separate things in different files, is that my issue?

Comment: Define "not working". Also, we don't much like external links here. If you have some code to show, then show it directly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the existing answer didn't work (or the next time you ask a question), could you please provide a [mre] (especially focus on the "minimal" part) so that people trying to help have something to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are enabling Debug Report extension, but then you try using Debug Utils messenger instead.

Comment: I feel extremely stupid and thankful at the same time! Thank you!